# Can Iron Heart Surge remove a Necrotic Cyst?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tome-of-battle

Plain and simple, by RAW can the Iron Heart Surge maneuver from the Tome of Battle remove a Necrotic Cyst, a spell from Libris Mortis.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. *iron heart surge* only removes an effect with a duration of one or more rounds. *Necrotic cyst*'s duration is instantaneous.

Comment: Iron heart surge can remove effects which last more than one round not just spells, and the cyst seems like a permanent effect to me